# TortoiseSVN - How to know from which working copy a file was checked in?

Tags: git, svn, path, tortoisesvn, working-copy

I have many working copies of same repository on my PC, they are in different folders.

I was just looking at the SVN log of a file I checked in some time ago and I can't remember from which working copy on my PC I did such check in.

**Is it possible looking at the SVN repo log to see from which working copy a certain file revision was checked in?** I don't know if the log stores somewhere such information.

---

FMY: is it possible in GIT/Mercurial ?

Comment: In git, you don't usually create many working copies. You create many branches and work on them instead. Give it a try, you might get hooked ;)

Comment: @ThachMai, you _will_ get hooked!

Comment: Can you explain what difference would it make for you? I'm not saying that it doesn't, just want to understand the question in order to come up with possible workarounds.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot: let's say I have N projects I'm developing all together. They all use a library `LIBX` that is on the repository. Each project keeps inside its own working copy of the `LIBX`. In one of this project I checked in a new version of `LIBX/FileY`. Now I'm looking for that project/working copy, but I can't find it. So I need to open all N projects one by one on my local drive to see in which one `FileY` is already up to date with the repository.

Comment: Well, can't suggest anything better than the obvious: if N is small - do it by hand. If it's large - write a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in SVN. In Git/Mercurial there's no such thing as a check-in. The closest equivalent would be committing locally and pushing to a remote repository. In which case, you also can't see specifically where that commit came from (although you can of course see the associated user.)

For both SVN and Git/Mercurial, you could change the user for each working copy and use that for identification purposes although it's unclear to me why that would be necessary.

Comment: thanks, could you explain when you say: "it's unclear to me why that would be necessary"?

Comment: Why would you want to tell which working copy a commit came from? In all situations I've encountered, knowing the user who made the commit is enough.

Comment: because the user is always me, but I have many working copies. Read the comment in reply to malenkiy_scot

Comment: Got it. Makes sense :) I can see how that would be useful. FWIW, this is a typically non-issue when using something like Git or Mercurial because the structure of your repository will be different.

Comment: interesting, when I'll have time I'll definietly give a try to either Git or Mercurail, I was waiting for the market to stabilize toward one of them, so I don't waste time learning one and then and moving to the other, in case I make the wrong choice.

Comment: I've used both Git and Mercurial and I would strongly recommend git. Not only do I think it's superior, but it also interoperates relatively seamlessly with both SVN and Mercurial.